# how do I enter the password when using cURL to access Cloudant data in Bluemix on Windows?

Tags: curl, ibm-cloud, cloudant

I want to use cURL from the DOS box in Windows to access Cloudant in Bluemix. This is is described in the Cloudant documentation https://cloudant.com/accessing-the-api-using-curl-tutorial/ and works as advertised, except for one thing:
I get prompted to manually enter the password to my Cloudant instance.

Since the Cloudant password is 64 alphanumeric characters which as far as I can see cannot be copied into the DOS BoX command line window. So how do I do it? Doing it manually is not really a viable option. ,

Comment: you can try input redirects http://www.lagmonster.org/docs/DOS7/pipes.html It says it works in dos

Answer (score 0):

You could put your credentials in a netrc file and use the curl `-n` / `--netrc` argument:

> ```
> -n, --netrc
> ```
>
> Makes curl scan the .netrc (_netrc on Windows) file in the user's home directory for login name and password. This is typically used for
>   FTP on Unix. If used with HTTP, curl will enable user authentication.
>   See netrc(5) ftp(1) for details on the file format. Curl will not
>   complain if that file doesn't have the right permissions (it should
>   not be either world- or group-readable). The environment variable
>   "HOME" is used to find the home directory.
>
> A quick and very simple example of how to setup a .netrc to allow curl to FTP to the machine host.domain.com with user name 'myself' and
>   password 'secret' should look similar to:
>
> ```
> machine host.domain.com login myself password secret
> ```

Source: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html